# Tensorflow TFGAN GANEstimator export model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I spend some frustrating hours to write a simple model export and import with a GANEstimator but I just couldn't get it working. Basically it's a conditional GAN with GANEstimator, the last 4 LOC is the export. The last line throws:

```
ValueError: export_outputs must be a dict and not<class 'NoneType'>
```

I would really appreciate if someone can take a look at this. As I said, I just want to train the model and export it and in another python script, I want to reload the model (rather say the generator) and feed in data somehow. Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
#import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
#tfe.enable_eager_execution()

tfgan = tf.contrib.gan
slim = tf.contrib.slim
layers = tf.contrib.layers
ds = tf.contrib.distributions

import time
import datasets.download_and_convert_mnist as download_and_convert_mnist
from mnist import data_provider,util
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy

from common import *
MODEL_FILE_NAME = 'cond_garden_experimental'
MODEL_SAVE_PATH = os.path.join(MODEL_SAVE_PATH, MODEL_FILE_NAME)
IMGS_SAVE_PATH = os.path.join(IMGS_SAVE_PATH, MODEL_FILE_NAME)




#constants and variables
num_epochs = 2000
batch_size = 32
latent_dims = 64

from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_util
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops

def _get_shape(tensor):
  tensor_shape = array_ops.shape(tensor)
  static_tensor_shape = tensor_util.constant_value(tensor_shape)
  return (static_tensor_shape if static_tensor_shape is not None else
          tensor_shape)

def condition_tensor(tensor, conditioning):
  tensor.shape[1:].assert_is_fully_defined()
  num_features = tensor.shape[1:].num_elements()
  mapped_conditioning = layers.linear(
      layers.flatten(conditioning), num_features)
  print(mapped_conditioning.shape)
  if not mapped_conditioning.shape.is_compatible_with(tensor.shape):
    mapped_conditioning = array_ops.reshape(
        mapped_conditioning, _get_shape(tensor))
  return tensor + mapped_conditioning




def conditional_discriminator_fn(img, inputs, weight_decay=2.5e-5):
    one_hot_labels = inputs[1]
    with slim.arg_scope(
            [layers.conv2d, layers.fully_connected],
            activation_fn=leaky_relu, normalizer_fn=None,
            weights_regularizer=layers.l2_regularizer(weight_decay),
            biases_regularizer=layers.l2_regularizer(weight_decay)):
        net = layers.conv2d(img, 64, [4, 4], stride=2)
        net = layers.conv2d(net, 128, [4, 4], stride=2)
        net = layers.flatten(net)
        net = condition_tensor(net, one_hot_labels)
        net = layers.fully_connected(net, 1024, normalizer_fn=layers.batch_norm)

        return layers.linear(net, 1)

leaky_relu = lambda net: tf.nn.leaky_relu(net, alpha=0.01)

global_noise = None
global_condition = None

def conditional_generator_fn(inputs, weight_decay=2.5e-5):
    if isinstance(inputs,dict):
        noise, one_hot_labels = inputs['noise'],inputs['condition']
    else:
        noise, one_hot_labels = inputs
        global global_noise
        global global_condition
        global_noise = noise
        global_condition = one_hot_labels
    with slim.arg_scope(
            [layers.fully_connected, layers.conv2d_transpose],
            activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, normalizer_fn=layers.batch_norm,
            weights_regularizer=layers.l2_regularizer(weight_decay)):
        net = layers.fully_connected(noise, 1024)
        net = condition_tensor(net, one_hot_labels)
        net = layers.fully_connected(net, 7 * 7 * 128)
        net = tf.reshape(net, [-1, 7, 7, 128])
        net = layers.conv2d_transpose(net, 64, [4, 4], stride=2)
        net = layers.conv2d_transpose(net, 32, [4, 4], stride=2)
        # Make sure that generator output is in the same range as `inputs`
        # ie [-1, 1].
        net = layers.conv2d(net, 1, 4, normalizer_fn=None, activation_fn=tf.tanh)

        return net


def _get_train_input_fn(batch_size, noise_dims, dataset_dir=None, num_threads=4):
  def train_input_fn():
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
      images, labels, _ = data_provider.provide_data('train', batch_size, dataset_dir, num_threads=num_threads)
    noise = tf.random_normal([batch_size, noise_dims])
    return ((noise,labels),images)
  return train_input_fn


def _get_predict_input_fn():
  def predict_input_fn(params):
      noise,condition = params['noise'],params['condition']
      noise_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(noise)
      condition_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(condition)
      #with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
      #    images, condition_tensor, _ = data_provider.provide_data('train', batch_size, MNIST_DATA_DIR, num_threads=4)
      #    noise_tensor = tf.random_normal([batch_size, latent_dims])
      print(noise_tensor.shape,condition_tensor.shape)
      return ((noise_tensor,condition_tensor),None)

  return predict_input_fn


def visualize_training_generator(train_step_num, start_time, data_np):
    """Visualize generator outputs during training.

    Args:
        train_step_num: The training step number. A python integer.
        start_time: Time when training started. The output of `time.time()`. A
            python float.
        data: Data to plot. A numpy array, most likely from an evaluated TensorFlow
            tensor.
    """
    print('Training step: %i' % train_step_num)
    time_since_start = (time.time() - start_time) / 60.0
    print('Time since start: %f m' % time_since_start)
    print('Steps per min: %f' % (train_step_num / time_since_start))
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(data_np), cmap='gray')
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(IMGS_SAVE_PATH,MODEL_FILE_NAME+str(train_step_num)+'.png'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup_clean_directory(MODEL_SAVE_PATH)
    setup_clean_directory(IMGS_SAVE_PATH)
    #prepare data
    download_and_convert_mnist.run(MNIST_DATA_DIR)
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        images, one_hot_labels, _ = data_provider.provide_data('train', batch_size, MNIST_DATA_DIR)

    gan_estimator = tfgan.estimator.GANEstimator(
        MODEL_SAVE_PATH,
        generator_fn=conditional_generator_fn,
        discriminator_fn=conditional_discriminator_fn,
        generator_loss_fn=tfgan.losses.wasserstein_generator_loss,
        discriminator_loss_fn=tfgan.losses.wasserstein_discriminator_loss,
        generator_optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001, 0.5),
        discriminator_optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001, 0.5),
        add_summaries=tfgan.estimator.SummaryType.IMAGES)
    train_input_fn = _get_train_input_fn(batch_size, noise_dims=latent_dims, dataset_dir=MNIST_DATA_DIR)
    gan_estimator.train(train_input_fn, max_steps=1)


    #try 1
    from tensorflow.python.estimator.export import export
    feat_dict = {'noise':global_noise,'condition':global_condition}
    sirf = export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(feat_dict)
    gan_estimator.export_savedmodel(EXPORT_DIR_ROOT, sirf)
```

Comment: I don't see `export_outputs` anywhere in your code, can you point us to what line that is being generated on? It says that you're trying to feed in a `None` type, meaning it's null, when it should have some data in it.

Comment: It is inside `export_savedmodel`. As I understand, this takes just the input tensors and build up the model with those input tensors (which are may be different from training) and this graph is exported. However, the output node is None and I don't know why.

Answer (score 5):

**2018-5-09**: Currently GANEstimator does not create said `export_output` dictionary; it can be verified by looking at `tensorflow/contrib/gan/python/estimator/python/head_impl.py` after line 162.

You can track the status of this issue via this [GitHub Pull Request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/19545).

The `model_fn` needs to return an `EstimatorSpec` with an `export_outputs` dictionary. Something along the lines of:

```
if mode == Modes.PREDICT:
    predictions = {
        'classes': tf.gather(label_values, predicted_indices),
        'scores': tf.reduce_max(probabilities, axis=1)
    }
    export_outputs = {
        'prediction': tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(predictions)
    }
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode, predictions=predictions, export_outputs=export_outputs)
```